# How to know what node is not valid with XMLTYPE

Tags: oracle, plsql, xmltype

Here is the code to validate an xml file in PL_SQL using XMLTYPE

```
doc := dbms_xmldom.newdomdocument;

...  xml file is build

v_xml:=DBMS_XMLDOM.GETXMLTYPE(doc);
v_schema:=v_xml.createSchemaBasedXML('xml.xsd');

BEGIN
  v_schema.schemavalidate();

EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
  dbms_output.put_line('XML File is not valid');
END;
```

Is there way to know where the file is not valid, what node ?

Thank you

Note : the exception hidden that way is this one :

```
ORA-31154: invalid XML document
ORA-19202: Error occurred in XML processing
LSX-00333: literal "" is not valid with respect to the pattern
```

Comment: Please show a [mcve] with data,and the exact exception error, which you are hiding

Comment: Are u the one putting minus one on the question ?

Comment: Um, no..... ...

Answer (score 0):

dbms_utility.format_error_stack is providing more error details, including LSX error messages, which gives you the type of validation error, like

> dbms_output.put_line( dbms_utility.format_error_stack);

ORA-31154: invalid XML document

ORA-19202: Error occurred in XML processing

LSX-00220: "" is wrong length, should be 12

ORA-06512: at "SYS.XMLTYPE", line 354